# Using replace to take a character and change it to another in java

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to remove certain characters to make it English after it being in l33t speak. For example, I 54w 3 5hip5, would translate to I saw 3 ships. I need the 3 to stay a 3 here but in, N3v3r f0rg37 y0|_|r t0w31, I would need the 3's to become e's. Here is my code as follows. All the characters translate over correctly, but I just can't figure out how to do the 3's to e's.

My question is, what is needed to be added to get the 3's to be e's at a certain time, and to have my 3's stay 3's another time.  Just so that you know, is that we aren't allowed to use regex, arrays, or string builder for this.

Rules are that if the number is supposed to be a number that it stays a number when you translate it from l33t to English, if the l33t number is a letter than you replace the number and turn it into the letter that corresponds to it.

I also have a different block of code that already takes into consideration the 3 to e's, but instead adds two u's instead of one.

Here are the replacements for the letters, a = 4, b = 8, e = 3, l = 1, o = 0, s = 5, t = 7, u = |_|, z = 2.

I decided to go the route of mike's answer since I understand exactly what's going on.

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: What are the replacement rules? When do you have to replace a digit, and when not?

Comment: You've got to be clearer on what you can and can't do, and what *specific* cases can and can't occur. There's no silver bullet here - but obviously a solution if you're being asked educationally.

Comment: _"regex, arrays, or string builder"_ Basically it sounds like you can't use all the things that make this possible. `replace` is non-discriminate and replaces all occurrences.

Comment: it seems like you should only replace 3 with an e if it is **not** a number. I would say that you could test if each word can be parsed to an integer, and if not, replace the 3 with e. same with all the numbers.

Comment: @mikeyaworski Supposedly the OP can't use arrays so they can't split it in to words. Unfortunately for them this makes it all or nothing.

Comment: @Radiodef I agree somewhat, but there must be a solution. Perhaps he could iterate over the `String`'s `chars` and then determine the regions in which there are words and test from there, instead of using a `.split` command. I'm sure there are still conditions he can test (very inefficiently) to do it.

Comment: @mikeyaworski The problem is the OP wants to use replace to do the replacement and replace necessarily replaces _all_ occurrences in the phrase. I wonder if they can use substring and concatenation which would make this possible without regex, arrays and StringBuilder. If this is not part of the assignment the OP needs to loosen his/her requirements.

Comment: For those who might want to use regex, this works: `.replaceAll("(?<! )3(?!= )", "e")`

Comment: All of those are part of the requirement for the assignment, and we can use substring and concatenation.

Comment: Try my answer before you go in a different direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Input/Output examples

This following code translates

> I 54w 3 5hip5

to

> I saw 3 ships

and

> 3 5hip5 4r3 c0ming m3 w4y

to

> 3 ships are coming me way

---

#### Code

```
public static String translateToEnglish(String phrase) {

    if (phrase == null)
        return null;

    boolean threeAtBeginning = false, threeAtEnd = fal;

    if (phrase.charAt(0) == '3' && phrase.charAt(1) == ' ')
        threeAtBeginning = true;      

    int length = phrase.length();

    if (phrase.charAt(length - 1) == '3' && phrase.charAt(length - 2) == ' ')
        threeAtEnd = true;

    String finished = phrase.replace('4', 'a') .replace('1', 'l') .replace('2', 'z') .replace('5', 's') .replace('8', 'b') .replace('0', 'o') .replace('7', 't') .replace("|_|", "u")  .replace("3", "e");
    finished = finished.replace(" e ", " 3 ");

    if (threeAtBeginning)
        finished = '3' + finished.substring(1);   
    if (threeAtEnd)
        finished = finished.substring(0, length - 1) + '3'; 

    return finished;
}
```

Comment: I think this will be the direction I will go, since I understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: I fixed your other code as well lol. I'll post another answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it.

```
 public static String translateToEnglish(String phrase) {
    if (phrase == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String finished = phrase.replace('4', 'a') .replace('1', 'l') .replace('2', 'z') .replace('5', 's') .replace('8', 'b') .replace('0', 'o') .replace('7', 't') .replace("|_|", "u")  .replace("3", "e");
    finished = finished.replace(" e ", " 3 ");

    if(finished.startsWith("e ")){
        finished = "3 " + finished.substring(2);
    }
    if(finished.endsWith(" e")){
        finished = finished.substring(0, finished.length()-2) + " 3";
    }

    return finished;

}
```

Comment: The only problem with that approach is if it is, 3 num83r5, it comes out as e numbers, when the e should be a 3.

Comment: finished = finished.replace(" e ", " 3 "); will fix that

Comment: What about `"I 54w 33 5hip5"` or `"I 54w 45 5hip5"`?

Comment: @bkail Those aren't apart of the test sentences. And those would be part of extra credit too.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof I had the line of code you had already inputed, and still didn't work, it would still print out the 3 as an e if it is at the beginning.

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Yes I did.

Comment: StringBuilder apparently isn't allowed either.

Comment: He said he couldn't use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly homework, and the restrictions are clearly intended to prevent any sane solution, but here's an O(n^2) solution that seems to avoid the restrictions:

```
public class RemoveL33t {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeL33t("I 54w 3 5hip5"));
    System.out.println(removeL33t("I 54w 33 5hip5"));
    System.out.println(removeL33t("I 54w 45 5hip5"));
    System.out.println(removeL33t("N3v3r f0rg37 y0|_|r t0w31"));
  }

  public static String removeL33t(String s) {
    String result = "";
    for (int pos = 0;;) {
      // Find the beginning of the next word.
      int whitespaceBegin = pos;
      while (pos < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(pos))) {
        pos++;
      }

      // Add the whitespace to the result.
      result += s.substring(whitespaceBegin, pos);

      // If there is no next word, then we're done.
      if (pos >= s.length()) {
        return result;
      }

      // Find the end of the word. Determine if the word is entirely numbers.
      int wordBegin = pos;
      boolean nonNumber = false;
      while (pos < s.length() && !Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(pos))) {
        nonNumber |= s.charAt(pos) < '0' || s.charAt(pos) > '9';
        pos++;
      }

      // Append the word.  Perform replacements if it contains a non-number.
      if (nonNumber) {
        result += s.substring(wordBegin, pos)
            .replace('4', 'a')
            .replace('8', 'b')
            .replace('3', 'e')
            .replace('1', 'l')
            .replace('0', 'o')
            .replace('5', 's')
            .replace('7', 't')
            .replace("|_|", "u")
            .replace('2', 'z');
      } else {
        result += s.substring(wordBegin, pos);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't use string builder either.

Comment: Fine. Here's a solution that works but that you probably can't use.

Comment: @itsaferbie You'll have to loosen your requirements somehow. The requirements in your OP taken literally (uses replace, does not use arrays, regex nor StringBuilder) are mutually exclusive. If your request is not part of the assignment then you can't apply the assignment's restrictions on us.

Comment: All the requirements are part of the assignment's requirements.

Comment: @Radiodef "uses replace" was not one of the requirements.  I don't see anything that says that `String.replace` must be used.  There are other ways to replace characters without using `String.replace`.  Also, even if they can't use `StringBuilder` there's nothing preventing them from building strings themselves with `s1 = s1 + s2` or `s1 += s2`, is there?

Comment: @ajb It's in the question title and their original code example.

Comment: @itsaferbie was it one of the requirements that you have to use the `replace()` method of `String`?

Comment: @ajb If they are allowed to use substring and concatenation then you can basically ignore my comment above (made before they answered my question) since this is possible in a number of ways including with replace. I think bkail's solution is valid in that case.

Comment: This looks like O(n) to me, not O(n^2).  You may be processing each character two or three times when you scan ahead, but I think the maximum number of times each character is scanned is a small constant, not proportional to the string length.  Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @ajb The O(n^2) comes from the += operator, which is implemented by creating a new string that concatenates the old and new, and since this is done in the O(n) scanning/outer loop, you end up *copying* O(n^2) characters. For example, if the string is "|_| |_| |_| ...". The first iteration copies result=""+"u" (1), the second iteration "u"+" u" (3), then "u u"+" u" (5), then "u u u"+" u" (7), etc. (ignoring the constant factor for the whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer, but is the best i could think of

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String c = "I 54w 45 5hip5";
    for(String s: c.split(" ")){
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            s = s.replace('4', 'a').replace('1', 'l').replace('2', 'z').replace('5', 's').replace('8', 'b').replace('0', 'o').replace('7', 't').replace("|_|", "u").replace("3", "e");
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: that would be using an array. the tough part of the question is to not use that, regex, or `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your "new" code that you decided to use, or this could just be an alternate solution. The input/output is identical to the samples I gave in my other answer:

```
public static String translateToEnglish(String phrase) {
    if (phrase == null)
        return null;
    String finished = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        char c = phrase.charAt(i);
        if (c == '4')
            finished += 'a';
        else if (c == '3') {
            if (i != phrase.length() - 1)
            {
                if (phrase.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {
                    if (i == 0)
                        finished += c;
                    else 
                        if (phrase.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')
                            finished += c;
                        else
                            finished += 'e';
                } 
                else
                    finished += 'e';
            }
            else
            {
                if (phrase.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')
                    finished += c;
                else
                    finished += 'e';
            }
        } else if (c == '1')
            finished += 'l';
        else if (c == '2')
            finished += 'z';
        else if (c == '5')
            finished += 's';
        else if (c == '7')
            finished +='t';
        else if (c == '8')
            finished += 'b';
        else if (c == '0')
            finished += 'o';
        else if (i + 2 < phrase.length() && phrase.charAt(i + 1) == '_' && phrase.charAt(i + 2) == '|') {
            finished += 'u';
            i += 2;
        } else
            finished += c;
    }
    return finished;
}
```